# Getting error: 409 Conflict when Deploying WebApp to Azure

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, devops

I'm trying to deploy a Node.js/Mongo webapp to Azure using the instructions in the MS Docs.  Specifically, it uses a deploymentLocalGitUrl which I have my local repo set to track.  When doing a push, the connection was interrupted, and now when I try to do a `git push azure master`, I get the following error:

```
$ git push azure master
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 6.47 KiB | 3.23 MiB/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 409 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 409 Conflict
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

How do I resolve this and get my local repo to push to the remote Azure site? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try to:

- Clone the repository to a different folder
- Copy the changed files from the old repository to the new
- Try `git push` from the new repository

It seems like something got messed up in the local file tracking mechanism when the connection got interrupted, so trying to use a "fresh copy" might solve the problem.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I have to ctrl-c kill the deploy (it seems to hang sometimes) this happens.  Simply waiting a minute to 5 seems to clear out whatever logjam is in the way.

Comment: Well it has been almost an hour now and it still fails.  I'm liking Azure less and less each day.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do here is unstage your last commit (assuming that's the one that you lost connection during)

Simple unstage command: git reset HEAD~1

For me, after unstaging a failed push, I can push new updates successfully.
Hope it works for anyone searching!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Azure's internal GIT repository got conflicted.

Try the following:

- Click "Disconnect" in the Deployment Center GIT source (see picture below), and reconnect again
- Restart the VM
- Switch to a different Python version
- Re-create the entire AZ Functions instance

[image]